# How to make static variables inside a class, which can only be modified by the class only and not it's instances?

Tags: java, oop, static

How to create a class variable which can only be modified by the class only and not it's instances

```
class BullDog{
    String name;
    static String breed = "BullDog";

    public BullDog(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class MainClass{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Dog Mydog = new BullDog("Fluffy");
        Mydog.breed = "Shepherd"; // Should not be modified

        System.out.Println(Dog.breed);
    }
}
```

Real Output:

```
Shepherd
```

Desired Output:

```
BullDog
```

Comment: Make it `private`?

Comment: You can't.  A static variable is accessible by the instances of that class.

Comment: @Babyburger What should I do then.

Comment: It sounds like you need a separate `static final` variable for the class and a non-static variable for the instances.

Comment: And if you wanted to have subclasses `EnglishBullDog` and `FrenchBullDog`? This is *not* a good design for inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

Make the field `final` that is constant. And `static final` is on class level.

```
public class BullDog {
    public String name;
    public static final String breed = "BullDog";

    public BullDog(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The problem is that inheritance is not possible. A Poodle needs its own static breed, and you cannot have a Dog providing a breed

```
public abstract class Dog {
    public String name;

    public Dog(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public abstract String getBreed();   
}

public class BullDog extends Dog {

    public BullDog(String name){
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String getBreed() {
        return "Bulldog";
    }
}

public class Poodle extends Dog {

    public Poodle(String name){
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String getBreed() {
        return "Wolf";
    }
}

List<Dog> dogs = Arrays.asList(new BullDog("fluffy"), new Poodle("Herman"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the static variable private. Refer to [this](https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/access-modifiers-java/amp/) for details.